# Sonatype NXRM - Asset Name Matcher

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, nexus, sonatype

Using NXRM OSS version 3.20.1, trying to configure Asset Name Matcher to exclude from deletion,

For example my components:

```
    com/foo/master/test.tgz
    com/foo/branch1/test.tgz
    com/foo/branch2/test.tgz
```

Which regex should be used to delete all **except** master.

I have tried using elastic regexp, but with no success.

Thanks!

Comment: So what **did** you try?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/regexp-syntax.html#regexp-optional-operators

`@&~(master)`

Comment: Try `@&~(.*master.*)`